# Relation between absolute continuity with respect to lebesgue measure and compact sets on R

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\mathbb{R},\text{Borel sets on }\mathbb{R})$, which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Then, is it true that, $\mu(K) < \infty$ for any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb R$?

A proof will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $\mu(A) = \int_A \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$.  Then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite: let $A_n = (-\infty, -\frac{1}{n}) \cup \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{n}, \infty)$, and then $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ and $\bigcup_n A_n = \mathbb{R}$.  Also, $\mu$ is absolutely continuous to Lebesgue measure, but $\mu([-1,1])=\infty$.